# How to draw on image instead of canvas with zoom and undo functionality in android?

Tags: android

I want to make an app in which user can draw on image instead of canvas and after that he/she can zoom image with undo functionality. can anyone help me in my project? or is there any library to do the same? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly , you can draw a bitmap of image on the canvas of same width & height. and use drawableview library for it. you will need to take out the files from library and make yours if you want to make changes as above.

Comment: where is library?

Comment: https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/DrawableView there you go my friend.